# Check VPN connection status (connect/disconnect) from the command line

Tags: command-line, network-manager, vpn

How to check that a VPN connection is connected or disconnected using command line?

Answer (score 17):

If you want to know if **any** VPN-connection is active then the following invocation is useful:

```
nmcli con | grep -i vpn
```

Depending of the connection status you will get either

```
VPN099     ...  vpn              wlan0
```

if active or

```
VPN099     ...  vpn               ---
```

if inactive.

Answer (score 17):

This will show just the active connections:

```
nmcli con show --active
```

And you can grep for vpn, if needed:

```
nmcli con show --active | grep -i vpn
```

Comment: Limiting this to just the active connections is definitely a good plan.  I'm not sure why you included the `-i` in the `grep` though.  The output is probably not going to change case and you might match those letters in a wifi SSID.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is great and 100% works for me

> **nmcli con show --active**

But when I started use *openconnect as Cisco Anyconnect alternative*, instead of:

> nmcli con show --active | grep -i **vpn**

I had to use next:

> nmcli con show --active | grep -i **tun**

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using `nmcli` command:

```
nmcli con status id your-vpn-connection-name
```

If your VPN connection is connected, you will see the connection information but if your VPN connection is disconnected, you will see something like this:

```
Error: 'your-vpn-connection-name' is not an active connection.
```

Comment: Also you can use `route -n`or `ifconfig` or ....

Comment: hm, which id should I use here? Running `nmcli con status [uuid] [name]` gives just an error: `COMMAND := { show | up | down | add | modify | edit | delete | monitor | reload | load }
`.

Comment: I think `status` deprecated or something in Ubuntu 18.04 and nmcli version 1.16.0: `Error: argument 'status' not understood. Try passing --help instead.`